# How to implement NAT traversal for P2P chat application which uses HTTP for communication?

Tags: networking

How to implement NAT traversal for P2P chat application which uses HTTP for communication? I red that the solution with UDP is more easy to implement. But I have to use HTTP, therefore I think I should use TCP. What is the appropriate approaches can be implemented? Should I use STUN? HTTP tunnel?